# use of cURL library

Tags: c++, iphone, ios6

I want to write common code that work for both iPhone and android. For that I want to use cURL library that work fine for android but for iOS it gives me following error:

```
(null): "_curl_easy_cleanup", referenced from:
(null): "_curl_easy_init", referenced from:
(null): "_curl_easy_perform", referenced from:
(null): "_curl_easy_setopt", referenced from:
(null): "_curl_easy_strerror", referenced from:
(null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Above error indicate some linking error for libcurl.a. I am not able to find out proper solution. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Have you added libcurl.a to the linking process of your app's compilation in XCode? If this were GCC it would be by adding a flag like `-lcurl` but I am not too sure about XCode.

Try this:
`XCode -> Click on your project -> Your Target -> Build Settings -> Linking -> other Linker flags` - here add `-lcurl`
The path to the library might need to be added in `Build Settings -> Search paths -> Library Search Paths`

Comment: Hello,I Tried above but still having same issue.

Comment: If the library is `compiled/ downloaded correctly`, `installed in the correct place`, `its path included in Xcode`, and `option added to link against it`, then im out of ideas sorry

Comment: can you explain me whole process from scratch? (step by step) And also provide me link to download library.

Comment: Hi, Im sorry, I havent done it personally so dont have any major insights, however a simple google of "compile curl for ios" does yield many useful looking results, some of which even provide precompiled libs and instructions to use them.